# Should you save the state in a page with infinite scrolling?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, search, infinite-scroll

- I have a page with infinite scrolling on it.
- I display news in descending order of time and new items keep coming in
- When people go to the bottom of the page, they load more items automatically and this goes on till my database is not exhausted
- I also have a search bar at the top of my page letting people search news
- Here is my concern, user loads page, user scrolls down 4 pages
- User types something in search box, the 4 pages are completely gone and we have 50 new results instead relevant to the user's search
- User clears search, now we load 50 default items once again

**Should I save the state of the page when user jumps between searches?**

- Example, user loads page, goes down 4 pages
- User types "Election news" in the search box, default state is stored in local storage with 200 results
- User searches "UK news" in the search box, election news with 50 items is stored in local storage
- user clears search box
- Default 200 items loaded from local storage instantly

Comment: infinite scroll means no pagination but you say 'scrolls down 4 pages'. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Twitter returns you to the state you left the app.

Comment: a page is 50 items, so even in infinite scroll when you scroll down 200 items, i consider that 4 pages because backend works on the concept of knowing where you left off

Comment: Your consideration does not mean anything to the reader if you use contradictory terms with the question's itself @PirateApp. You might have explain the same thing without using the word 'page'. Backend probably using a variable like 'contentItemCount' and it's just a parameter to specify the count of the items, nothing relation with the pages again. The parameter can be changeable on frontend if you don't have a restriction by the way (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please let the user return to his initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a new design function called 'recent searches' that are stored on cookies/ app and visually accessible on the page like in a side menu or when you click on search again? This may make your product more user personalizable, assuming its on the web.